# How long do Kubernetes Pods persist?

Tags: kubernetes

How long does a pod persist without a replication controller?

I have run some pods that have a very simple purpose, they execute and then terminate. Other pods like a database server pod persists for quite a longer time. However after a day or so, the pod would terminate. I know docker containers exit once their process has finished running, but why would my database pods continue running for a while and then randomly exit.

What controls the termination of a pod?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for you to find a definitive answer to that question would be to `kubectl describe pod <podName>`, or `kubectl get events`. Any pod termination would have an associated event that you can use to diagnose the reason.

Pods may die due to several reasons, ranging from errors within the container, to a node going down for maintenance. You can usually set the appropriate [RestartPolicy](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/pod-states/#restartpolicy), which will restart the pod if it fails (except in case of node failure). If you have multiple nods and would like the pod to be restarted on a different node, you should use a higher level controller like a ReplicaSet or Deployment.

For pods expected to terminate, a [job](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/jobs/) is better suited.